# Adding values to char* [][]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have been working around with building a simple shell in C. I am wanting to add a history built in function, but I need to know how to do the following:

I have a global variable commanHistory which, I believe is a pointer to an array of characters? (correct me if I am wrong please).

```
char *commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1];
```

Within my read line function, I want to store the ith line in the ith row of commandHistory. Here is what I am doing:

```
char *lsh_read_line(void)
{
  int bufsize = MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
  int position = 0;
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize);
  int c;
  int i = 0;

  if (!buffer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (1) {
    // Read a character
    c = getchar();

    // If we hit EOF, replace it with a null character and return.
    if (c == EOF || c == '\n') {
      buffer[position] = '\0';
      return buffer;
    } else {
      buffer[position] = c;
    }
    position++;

   // If we have exceeded the buffer, reallocate.
    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
      buffer = realloc(buffer, bufsize);
      if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  }
commandHistory[i++][0] = buffer; // wanting to store command i in commandHistory (also only want to keep track of 10 at a time)

}
```

When I call my built in function I just get 10 (null) printing out from this:

```
int lsh_history(char **args)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_COMMANDS; i++) {
    printf("  %s\n", commandHistory[i][0]);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: I am required to use a 2d array. This is the last part of building a shell that I am having trouble with. While I believe this can be done with a 1 dimensional array, I am following this part of instructions:

> Internally, your shell should save the command history in a 2-dimensional array:
>   char commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1];
>   Each row of this table will store one command. Viewing the rows arranged in a circle, a data
>   structure similar to a queue can be constructed. Unlike a traditional queue, your command
>   history will never overflow — as we continue to add commands, older commands will simply
>   be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

Your `commandHistory` is actually a **two-dimensinal** array of strings/char pointers, while you want a one dimensional one. You should declare it like this:

```
char *commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS];
```

and you don't need to worry about the string length at this point, since each command is allocated dynamically. And then to access the `i`'th string from this array you just need `commandHistory[i]`, which is of type `char *`.

**Update:** 
If you (or the instructor) insist on having  `commandHistory` declared as static two dimensional array:

```
 char commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1];
```

You should not allocate the buffer dynamically as you do, but **copy** the commands into corresponding place in your **statically pre-allocated** array `commandHistory` (i.e. instead of `buffer[position]=..` do `commandHistory[i][position] = ...`).

Comment: I was allocated the buffer dynamically because of these instructions per the instructor also: 

Use dynamic memory (e.g. malloc and realloc) to support arbitrarily large command line lengths.
Use dynamic memory (e.g. malloc and realloc) to support arbitrarily large command arguments.

Which I obviously handled before I worked on the history

Comment: @connormoore These things together do not make sense. Well, it can be done, but it's kind of waste. If you declare such an array, you have already covered all of the possibly needed memory space (the worst case of it).

Comment: hence my confusion.. for starters this is my first class involving C (operating systems class). The instructions are not making sense to me. I am having trouble at this point because of them.

Comment: Just pick one way, which seems more important to you (or instructor). Or ask for clarification. Sometimes instructors just don't know what they want.

Comment: I will ask if I can use a 1d array. It makes more sense to me that way.. if not I will take your advice on how to handle it.

Comment: Anyway, the first approach makes it more optimal on memory usage, but adding some overhead on allocating and freeing the memory, which should be done with care. The second one is much simpler in this sense, but more wasteful on memory resources and maybe less educational.

Comment: So, I am suppose to store the pointers into the 2d array. Is that not what I am doing here:
commandHistory[i++][0] = buffer;
If so/If not how do I get the values from there and print them like I need to?

Comment: It really doesn't make sense. You are using only the first array element out of `MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1` in each one of `MAX_COMMANDS` arrays, so basically "wasting" `MAX_COMMANDS*MAX_LINE_LENGTH` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make your command history an array of char*'s , i.e.:
char *commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS];
and copy the buffer pointer into the history entry (be careful; the history now "owns" the malloced space)

An alternative would be to make it a 2D array of chars, but then you couldn't accept your overly long commands (the ones for which you realloced buffer).